# AngularJS Hello World

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning AngularJS 2 using [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#create-and-configure) tutorial. I am using Windows 8. After running **npm install**,**npm run typings install** and **npm start** I saw 
[image]

in my browser. After that I checked the **cmd** and found like below screen shot.

[image]

I have a confusion here, I think the execution is not completed. Am I right ?

If execution is not completed, then when it will complete?

If the execution is completed then why it is looking like that ? It should display a folder path, isn't it?

I new in AngularJS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working ok this CMD enables angular to track changes in your code and populate them in your HTML without the need to refresh the page.
you can now check your website as you code on localhost on the following url
http://localhost:3000

Comment: thanks for your reply. How can I close the CMD ??. How to host this angular App in Production server?? Thanks

Comment: Angular is a frontend framework all you have to do is just copy and paste your files on your server using ftp and you are good to go , to close this cmd pree ctrl+c or just close the windows but once you do that the automatic update feature will stop and the you will have to start it again manually

Comment: You can use a node module "Express" for hosting your pages on server and run on that.